# Custom PMD rule with Gradle

Tags: gradle, pmd

I would like to use the gradle PMD plugin in an enterprise project which is built with gradle.

I have a `pmd_rules.xml` file which already works, but I can't add own java rules (I get a class not found exception). I followed the tutorial on it's website.

Where do I have to put my own rules so they get recognized by gradle and PMD? Has somebody already done something like that?

pmd.gradle:

```
apply from: rootProject.file("core/modules.gradle"), to : ext

if(project.name in (modules["modules"] +modules["modules"])){
    apply plugin: 'pmd'

    pmd {
        ignoreFailures = true
        ruleSetFiles = rootProject.files("../repo/pmd_rules.xml")
        sourceSets = [sourceSets.main,sourceSets.test]
        targetJdk = org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.TargetJdk.VERSION_1_7
        ruleSets = []
        toolVersion = "5.0.5"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tasks.withType(Pmd) {
    pmdClasspath += file("path/to/rules.jar")
}
```

Comment: Peter's answer is perfectly correct:
I asked the quesion also in the gradle forum: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/custom-rules-with-pmd-plugin.

Instead of overriding the pmdClasspath, I now add the file to the classpath with the "+="-Operator

Answer (score 0):

For latest Gradle [pmd](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/pmd_plugin.html) plugin you need to do the following things:

1. Add your library with pmd rules to plugin classpath
   https://github.com/dgroup/arch4u-pmd#gradle-buildgradle

   ```
   dependencies {
      ...
      pmd "io.github.groupid:libid:versionid"  
      pmd "commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0" 
      ...
   }
   ```
2. Include ruleset from your lib
   https://github.com/dgroup/arch4u-pmd#include-arch4u-pmd-rules-into-your-existing-custom-ruleset

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <ruleset name="pmd ruleset with your rules">

     ...
     <rule ref="io/github/path-to-ruleset-from-your-lib.xml"/>
     ...

   </ruleset>
   ```

   or define particular rules in your
   https://github.com/dgroup/arch4u-pmd#reconfigure-a-rule

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <ruleset name="pmd ruleset with your rules">

     ...
     <!-- 2. Reconfigure rule with expected property -->
     <rule name="RuleFromYourLibrary" class="io.github.RuleFromYourLibrary">
       <priority>3</priority>
       <properties>
         ...
       </properties>
     </rule>
     ...

   </ruleset>
   ```